# Importing specific text from Word

Tags: python

I have a couple hundred Word docs that have some number measurements that I need in my code. Naturally, I don't want to copy and paste the measurements into python each time. What I have tried to do is:

```
r = []
with open('NGC1705_rotmod.dat') as fo:
    for rec in fo:
        r.append(rec[0:4])
```

Which returns:

```
['# Di', '# Ra', '# kp', '0.22', '0.66', '1.11', '1.55', '2.00', '2.45', '2.89', '3.34', '3.78', '4.22', '4.66', '5.11', '5.56', '6.00']
```

However, the first three elements (`#Di, #Ra, #kp`) are simply the headers for the data, they aren't part of the data that I need. Is there any way to cut off the first 3 rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice)

```
from itertools import islice

r = []
with open('NGC1705_rotmod.dat') as fo:
    for rec in islice(fo, 3, None):
        r.append(rec[0:4])
```

Comment: Thank you, on a slightly unrelated note... do you happen to know how to append data for a numpy.array? I realized after I asked this question that I need r to be r = np.array([]) for later code. Since np.array doesn't support ".append", is there something that accomplishes the same thing except is compatible for np.array?

Comment: The easiest way would be to build `r` as above and then do `r = np.array(r)`. It's also worth noting that it's still strings at this point.

Comment: Oh, is there a quick way to convert an array of Strings to an array of ints?

Comment: I would do it when you're appending them to the list, before it becomes an array. And you probably want them to be floats.

Comment: Ya, I just did something like r = list(map(float, r)), although your way may be cleaner

Answer (score 0):

Yes, try this.  There is probably a cleaner way, but this should work.

```
r = []
with open('NGC1705_rotmod.dat') as fo:
    next(fo)
    next(fo)
    next(fo)
    for rec in fo:
        r.append(rec[0:4])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can track the line no there and then pass if the line no is 0 because header are only in line 0 so something like :

```
r = []
with open('NGC1705_rotmod.dat') as fo:

    for line_no,rec in enumerate(fo):
        if line_no==0:
            pass
        else:
            r.append(rec[0:4])
```